# What tools should I look into to approach taking ownership of website?

Tags: html, web, dreamweaver, web-development-server

I'm part of an organization that has a website, and I'm taking over that website to manage it for them. I have lots of experience with HTML, CSS, and JS, but no experience doing website admin. The only information I have right now is that the previous admin used Dreamweaver.

What information should I seek out in order to approach administrating a site in a scenario like this? The previous admin said that you can download software and use it to just take over administration of the existing site. How should I approach this?

Comment: Do you mean you want to manage the files on the server?

Comment: I'm not sure. All I know is that I want to be able to update and control everything on the site. I don't know what files, if any, are on a server.

Comment: If it's about managing the website files, then you may use winscp or any other SFTP software to view and update the files and folders on the webserver. In case you want the control of the remote machine i.e. the webserver you can use any SSH client like putty